# C# How to check if a string is misspelled

Tags: c#, spell-checking

I'm using C# to write a program that generates lines of text over and over. The user enters a set of numbers, 1-26, in whatever order, and the program matches each number to a letter.

The point is to have it go through every order of the alphabet until it eventually generates an actual word. For example, someone could enter 7-2-15-26-3, and it would eventually read that set of numbers as "hello".

I got the program to work and to print every outcome to a txt file, but because there are so many different possible outcomes, it is almost impossible to find an actual word in the file without going through every single line.

One of my tests only had 11 letters to choose from, it took a few minutes to finish and the txt file was so big, it would not open.

So my question is, does anyone know of a library or spell check that I could use to check if each string is an actual word? If I could check it each time, I could have it only print the outcomes that are words. I would have it check against preset words, but I won't always know what the outcome will be so I need to check against everything.

I have searched online but haven't found much. Again, I'm using C#. Thank you for any help.

Edit: Sorry about asking a question that had already been answered, I didn't see the other question before. I'll try the NHunspell and see how that works.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a dictionary and checking against it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I cannot see the whole picture here. English only or multiple languages?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Nhunspell](http://www.crawler-lib.net/nhunspell), it's free (.Net version of popular "Hunspell")

E.g.
    Check Spelling,
    bool correct = hunspell.Spell("Recommendation");

Get suggestions,

```
List<string> suggestions = hunspell.Suggest("Recommendatio");
```

[More c# code samples](http://www.crawler-lib.net/csharp-code-samples-nhunspell)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you incorporate an english dictionary into your application so that you have something to check against.

Every time a new word is generated, it checks through the dictionary and takes all the matching results through regex and returns null if no word matches.

Hope this helps.